# Azure AD B2C return 404 Error after authorized

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, azure-ad-b2c

I create a Dot net core Webapp (MVC) with a connection to Azure AD B2C.

In my project I follow the tutorial under https://elanderson.net/2019/04/asp-net-core-with-azure-b2c-auth/

It works fine when I us a webapp (not MVC / RazorPages). But when I use MVC after authentification it returns to https://localhost:44363/signin-oidc and give me a `404 Error`.

I add this to **startup.cs**

```
   using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AzureADB2C.UI;



   // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
      public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {

            services.AddAuthentication(AzureADB2CDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddAzureADB2C(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAdB2C", options));

            services.AddControllersWithViews();
        }
```

create the **_LoginPartial.cshtml**

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AzureADB2C.UI
@using Microsoft.Extensions.Options
@inject IOptionsMonitor<AzureADB2COptions> AzureADB2COptions

@{
    var options = AzureADB2COptions.Get(AzureADB2CDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
}


<ul class="navbar-nav">
    @if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        @if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(options.EditProfilePolicyId))
        {
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="AzureADB2C" asp-controller="Account" asp-action="EditProfile">
                    <span class="text-dark">Hello @User.Identity.Name!</span>
                </a>
            </li>
        }
        else
        {
            <li class="nav-item">
                <span class="navbar-text text-dark">Hello @User.Identity.Name!</span>
            </li>
        }
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="AzureADB2C" asp-controller="Account" asp-action="SignOut">Sign out</a>
        </li>
    }
    else
    {
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="AzureADB2C" asp-controller="Account" asp-action="SignIn">Sign in</a>
        </li>
    }
</ul>
```

Also, I add the parameter to my **appsettings.json**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please make sure you have added `app.UseAuthentication()` in Startup.Configure. That's what handles callback paths.

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            loggerFactory.AddConsole();
            loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
            loggerFactory.AddDebug();

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseBrowserLink();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            }

            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseSession();

            app.UseAuthentication();

            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
        }
```

Also, here is an [sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-dotnetcore-webapp) regarding how to build a MVC web application with Azure AD B2C.